# What is the best way to handle navigation routes with multiple authentication states using Bloc?

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, bloc, flutter-bloc, flutter-navigation

I need to implement authentication feature in my app where the user can have different states:

- Unauthenticated
- FirebaseAuthenticated
- FullyAuthenticated

The reason for these states is that I would like to gather and store extra user information like DOB and Username, **only after the user's ***first*** log in** with Firebase (Google Auth, Apple Sign In).

> The flow looks like this:
>
> - First time user
>
> -> App launch -> State.Unauthenticated -> Go to Login page 
> -> User signs in with Google or Apple -> State.FirebaseAuthenticated (new field `fullyAuthenticated = false` is stored in DB)  -> Go to DOB page (get
> DOB) -> Go to Username page (get username) -> State.FullyAuthenticated
> (`fullyAuthenticated = true` in DB) -> go to Home page
>
> - Existing user (Scenario 1)
>
> -> App launch -> State.FullyAuthenticated -> Go to Home page
>
> - Existing user (Scenario 2)
>
> -> App launch -> State.FirebaseAuthenticated -> Go to DOB page (get DOB) -> Go to Username page (get username) -> State.FullyAuthenticated
> (`fullyAuthenticated = true` in DB) -> go to Home page
>
> - Existing user (Scenario 3)
>
> -> App launch -> State.Unauthenticated -> Go to Login page
> -> User signs in with Google or Apple -> State.FullyAuthenticated (`fullyAuthenticated = true` in DB)  -> go to Home page

Existing AuthStates used with AuthCubit:

```
@immutable
abstract class AuthState {
  final User user;

  AuthState({this.user});

  User getUser(){
    return this.user;
  }
}

class AuthLoading extends AuthState {}

class AuthUnauthenticated extends AuthState {}

class AuthAuthenticated extends AuthState {
  final User user;
  final AuthenticationType authenticationType; //enum {FirebaseAuthenticated, FullyAuthenticated} 
  AuthAuthenticated({@required this.user, @required this.authenticationType});
 }
```

My problem is Navigation. I'm not sure how to handle it since, on app launch I have 4 different scenarios every time, and, I need to keep listening for any changes in AuthState to see if the user is at anytime Unauthenticated and kick him out to the LoginPage.

I'm using generated (named) routing as well since the main app flow is very complicated, so having a BlocBuilder that builds whether the LoginPage(), DOBPage(), or HomeScreen() page when the user state changes is not an option.

I just started experimenting with the Bloc architecture and I know that the desired flow stated above is very much achievable with Bloc.

I also have a `UserRepository` where I communicate with DB to store and retrieve User information. The `isFullyAuthenticated`, `DOB`, and `Username` fields are all stored there along with the firebase `tokenID`. Also, if you noticed, my AuthCubit also depends on whether the user is 'fully authenticated' or not which is retrieved from the `UserRepository`.

I'm looking for advice to set up this authentication architecture to fit my needs. I've already tried setting up Bloc Listener and Bloc Builder in my CupertinoApp().home but was not able to achieve the desired flow stated above.

I'm ready to answer and questions if this was not clear.

Thanks,
tester